# I want to know how to get Test1 value using Jsonpath

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

I want to know the value of "Test1" whose "createdTs" value is greater than or equal to 444.

```html
[
   {
"raw" : {
      "Test1":"Apple",
      "Test2":{
            "createdTs": 333,
            "langCode": "ko"
        }
    }
},
    {
"raw" : {
      "Test1":"Tomato",
      "Test2":{
            "createdTs": 555,
            "langCode": "ko"
        }
    }
}
]
```

Even if I call Jsonpath as shown below, it does not work.

```html
$[?(@.['Test2'].createdTs > 444)]
```

The result I want is like below.

```html
"raw" : {
      "Test1":"Tomato",
      "Test2":{
            "createdTs": 555,
            "langCode": "ko"
        }
    }
```

Comment: You also need to go through  [how to post a good question in stackoverflow.?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the path you need to specify all the attributes from parent node till the child node.

`$[?(@.raw.Test2.createdTs > 444)]`

Kindly go through the documentation completly to learn and understand how jayway jsonpath works. https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started

Online Test Tool : https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/